# Ayuda con diff en matlab

Tags: matlab

Tengo una duda.La función diff que hace?.

Por otro lado, si tengo esto:

```
X(diff(X)==0)=[]
```

y en X tengo los valores de X=[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1 0 0 0  0 0 0 3 3  3 3] que salida me da?. Lo he ejecutado en matlab para visualizar que es lo que me aparece pero no lo entiendo.

Answer (score 1):

**Función diff**

La función `diff` lo que hace es calcular la diferencia entre los elementos contiguos de una lista o matriz. Ejemplo:

```
>> X = [1,4,3,9,5];
>> diff(X)
ans =
     3    -1     6    -4
```

El primer elemento `3` resulta de la resta de los dos primeros números `4-1`. El `-1` resulta de restar el siguiente par `3-4`. Y así sucesivamente, de forma que el vector resultante siempre tiene un elemento menos que el inicial.

La función `diff` también puede tomar otros parámetros para realizar la operación de forma recursiva `n` veces y para seleccionar el eje sobre el que operar en caso de matrices. Puedes consultarlo [aquí](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html).

**Tu caso**

En cuanto al caso que planteas, la respuesta rápida es que el código **elimina los elementos *contiguos* iguales**.

La explicación es que, partiendo del vector que propones:

```
X = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3]
```

Se ejecuta la operación `diff`. Esto nos va a dar la diferencia entre los pares, que será un valor de `0` en los elementos contiguos iguales. Y nos dará un número diferente a `0` entre los elementos que sean diferentes.

```
>> diff_X = diff(X)
diff_X =
     0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0
```

Posteriormente compara `diff(X)` con `0`. Esto nos devuelve un vector de valores lógicos `1`'s y `0`'s, donde `1` es `true` y `0` es `false`.

De esta manera, se obtienen los índices de los elementos repetidos contiguos, codificados a `1`, mientras que solo queda `0` en uno de cada serie de números repetidos.

```
>> diff_X0 = diff_X == 0
diff_X0 =
  1×19 logical array
   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
```

Si comparas los elementos de los vectores a lo largo de las operaciones:

```
     X        -> [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3]
diff(X)       -> [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0  ]
diff(X) == 0  -> [1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1  ]
```

El último vector tiene `0` en el último elemento de cada conjunto.

Ahora, todo el término `diff(X) == 0` lo meten dentro de `X(...)`. Esto lo que hace es seleccionar en el vector `X` los elementos que estén a `1`.

Ejemplo (selecciona las posiciones 1, 3, 4, 5 y 8):

```
>> Y = [1,5,9,4,0,6,3,2];
>> Y([true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true])
ans =
     1     9     4     0     2
```

En el caso que planteas, se seleccionan los elementos de `X` y se asignan a "nada" `[]` (lista vacia). Es decir, se eliminan. Quedando una lista sin repeticiones *contiguas*.

```
>> X(diff(X)==0) = []
X =
     0     1     0     3
```

Puedes comprobar esto último sustituyendo `[]` por otro valor cualquiera:

```
>> X(diff(X)==0) = 89
X =
    89  89  89  89   0  89  89  89  89   1  89  89  89  89  89   0  89  89  89   3
```